# Why is a deleted file still writable in Linux

Tags: filesystems, file-descriptors

I'm using Linux for a while and today I found an interesting thing.

Saying that I have an infinite task, which keeps writing strings into a file.

At some moment, I delete the file, and in several seconds, I recreate the file. To my surprise, I won't lose any string.

Here is how I test with bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while :
do
    echo ${i}>>./target
    sleep 1
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

I execute this script for 4 seconds and I can get a file name `target`, which contains `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. Then I remove the file `target`. And I execute `touch target` to create a new file in 5 seconds. To my surprise, in the new file, I get the contents `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` immediately.

So why can I get back all of the strings, which are generated during deleting the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `touch target` isn’t creating the file in this instance. The `>>` shell operator appends to the named file, creating if necessary. You delete the file after “3”, and the subsequent `echo 4>>./target` creates it.

Trying listing the file after you delete it:

```
rm target; sleep 1; ls -l target
```

and you’ll see that it’s been re-created.